# Vertical align multiple lines of text to the middle

Tags: html, css

I need to align multiple lines of text to the middle. Here is a rough guide of the markup I am working with.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='#'>This should be centered.</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

[image: The element that needs to be centered]

So as you can see from my image, the "work" link should be centered vertically. I have the width and height set with `vertical-align: middle;`. I know you need to set the line height for it to actually work but theres the problem. If I set the line height to 72px (the height of the element) then some of the links will stretch down the page due to them taking up two lines.

[image: The broken center]

Is there a way of aligning multiple lines of text to the middle without using line-height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write like this

```
a{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

& you can give `display:table-cell;` to it like this

```
li {
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
}
```

but it's not work in IE7 & below

Comment: Nope, I am afraid this will not work either. You have to use the `line-height` property for this to work. Which ruins it when you have more than one line.

Comment: @Rich also came up with basically the same answer. But you came up with it first. I will have to accept yours. Thank you both!

Comment: In my experience, it seems like the child `a` doesn't need the `vertical-align:middle` property. It works fine to only have that applied to the parent, in this case `li`.

Answer (score 7):

Use display:table-cell; in your li element.

```
li {
width:200px;
height:200px;
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
}
```

This will give you this effect:

[image]

Comment: Okay this is more like it. Its just now the list looks like it has been set to `display: block;`. It has formed one big vertical line, not a horisontal one. Any idea how you can horizontally align table cells?

Comment: This solution gives you a horizontal line

Comment: Indeed it does. And it is close to what I want, although for this to work I need to have no size set for my links. So I guess this is my only option and I will just have to change where my `:hover` styles are applied to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change **display** to **block** for hyperlink and use paddings:

```
li a {display: block; padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px}
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. The elements all need to be a fixed height. Using padding would cause different heights for each element.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this to handle vertically-aligned 100% height/width anchors inside containers:

http://jsfiddle.net/khaustic/KDfN6/
markup:

```
<div class="links one">
    <a href="#">One</a>
</div>
<div class="links two">
    <a href="#">Two Two</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
* { 
    /*ie box model forever!*/
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.links {
    height: 5.0em;
    text-align:center;
    outline: 1px solid #333;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 1.0em;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.links.one { width: 8em; }
.links.two { width: 4em; }

.links a {
    width:10em;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: inherit;
}
```