# How do I vertically center text with CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `<div>` element which contains text and I want to align the contents of this `<div>` vertically center.

Here is my `<div>` style:

```css
#box {
  height: 170px;
  width: 270px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit
</div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: #box{line-height: -moz-block-height;}

Comment: you can use vertical-align: middle;

Comment: there are some css center generators which help to make decision which solution of centering is valid to use. F.e. I use [this one](http://howtocenterincss.com/).

Answer (score 3317, accepted):

You can try this basic approach:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World!
</div>
```

It only works for a single line of text though, because we set the line's height to the same height as the containing box element.

---

### A more versatile approach

This is another way to align text vertically. This solution will work for a single line and multiple lines of text, but it still requires a fixed height container:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

The CSS just sizes the `<div>`, vertically center aligns the `<span>` by setting the `<div>`'s line-height equal to its height, and makes the `<span>` an inline-block with `vertical-align: middle`. Then it sets the line-height back to normal for the `<span>`, so its contents will flow naturally inside the block.

---

### Simulating table display

And here is another option, which may not work on older [browsers that don't support `display: table` and `display: table-cell`](http://caniuse.com/css-table) (basically just Internet Explorer 7). Using CSS we simulate table behavior (since tables support vertical alignment), and the HTML is the same as the second example:

```css
div {
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

---

### Using absolute positioning

This technique uses an absolutely positioned element setting top, bottom, left and right to 0. It is described in more detail in an article in Smashing Magazine, *[Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)*.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Because it goes wrong if the div or text changes or more content is added.

Comment: But this is what he said, if you know how much text you will use its perfectly acceptable... the solution below is however more flexible

Comment: "padding:0" may also be needed in first option

Comment: But i would like to center the text only in vertically not horizontally, so whats the solution??

Comment: For the basic approach I tried, I wasn't able to achieve results when my `height` was in a `%` value, so I used `em` and that worked.

Answer (score 1598):

Another way (not mentioned here yet) is with [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Just add the following code to the **container** element:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* Align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* Align vertical */
```

### [Flexbox demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4rrL4/594/)

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
</div>
```

Alternatively, instead of aligning the content via the *container*, flexbox can also center a **flex item** with an [auto margin](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) *when there is only one flex-item in the flex container* (like the example given in the question above).

So to center the flex item both horizontally and vertically just set it with `margin:auto`

### [Flexbox Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4rrL4/815/)

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.box span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>margin:auto on a flex item centers it both horizontally and vertically</span> 
</div>
```

**NB:** All the above applies to centering items while laying them out in **horizontal rows**. This is also the default behavior, because by default the value for `flex-direction` is `row`. If, however flex-items need to be laid out in **vertical columns**, then `flex-direction: column` should be set on the container to set the main-axis as column and additionally the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties now work *the other way around* with `justify-content: center` centering vertically and  `align-items: center` centering horizontally)

### [`flex-direction: column` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4rrL4/888/)

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /* vertically aligns items */
  align-items: center;
  /* horizontally aligns items */
}
p {
  margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    When flex-direction is column...
  </p>
  <p>
    "justify-content: center" - vertically aligns
  </p>
  <p>
    "align-items: center" - horizontally aligns
  </p>
</div>
```

A good place to start with Flexbox to see some of its features and get syntax for maximum browser support is [flexyboxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

Also, browser support nowadays is very good: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

For cross-browser compatibility for `display: flex` and `align-items`, you can use the following:

```css
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: [Flexbox support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: This works perfect when some text is 1 line and others 2, or anytime you have different height elements. Best answer for me.

Comment: Had to use that solution, it applies to the inner text too. Though had to add `height: 100%;`

Comment: I kinda worry that overusing flexbox would cause performance trouble. Will it?

Comment: This was helpful to me because when I used line-height like the other solution said, it did not work on IOS.

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 153):

You can easily do this by adding the following piece of CSS code:

```css
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

That means your CSS finally looks like:

```css
#box {
  height: 90px;
  width: 270px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like that kills the margin attributes, though.

Comment: Works for me, if I set the parent div to `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`. Thanks

Comment: does not work on chrome..?

Comment: not working on firefox either

Answer (score 132):

For reference and to add a simpler answer:

Pure CSS:

```
.vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Or as a SASS/SCSS Mixin:

```
@mixin vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Use by:

```
.class-to-center {
    @include vertical-align;
}
```

By Sebastian Ekström's blog post *[Vertical align anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)*:

This method can cause elements to be blurry due to the element being placed on a “half pixel”. A solution for this is to set its parent element to preserve-3d. Like following:

```
.parent-element {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

We live in 2015+ and [Flex Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flex_Box_Layout) is supported by every major modern browser.

It will be the way websites are made from here on out.

***Learn it!***

Comment: Worked when others didn't

Answer (score 73):

All credit goes to this link owner @Sebastian Ekström [Link](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/); please go through this. See it in action [codepen](http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/kzEhe). By reading the above article I also created [a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hegvLmee/1/).

With just three lines of CSS (excluding vendor prefixes) we can do it with the help of a transform: translateY vertically centers whatever we want, even if we don’t know its height.

The CSS property transform is usually used for rotating and scaling elements, but with its translateY function we can now vertically align elements. Usually this must be done with absolute positioning or setting line-heights, but these require you to either know the height of the element or only works on single-line text, etc.

So, to do this we write:

```css
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

That’s all you need. It is a similar technique to the absolute-position method, but with the upside that we don’t have to set any height on the element or position-property on the parent. It works straight out of the box, even in [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9)!

To make it even more simple, we can write it as a mixin with its vendor prefixes.

Comment: This worked for me even for text and image combination also

Answer (score 56):

There is a tiny magic with CSS3 flexboxes:

```css
/* Important */
section {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}
section p {
    /* Key Part */
    margin: auto;
}


/* Unimportant, coloring and UI */
section {
    height: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    background-color: gold;
}
section p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cantarell, Calibri;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <p>
        I'm a centered box!<br/>
        Flexboxes are great!
    </p>
</section>
```

**Tip**: Replace the line above marked as "Key Part" with one of these lines, if you want to center the text:

1. Only vertically:

   ```css
   margin: auto 0;
   ```
2. Only horizontally:

   ```css
   margin: 0 auto;
   ```

As I noticed, this trick works with grids (i.e. `display: grid`), also.

Comment: Could you please explain why does flex have this effect in this case on centering the paragraph?

Comment: @elena In fact, I don't know exactly why, I discovered when I was trying. However, it would be a consideration for newer versions of CSS. For instance, if you change the display to grid in this case, it will be worked as the same as flexboxes. I think grids and flexboxes comes with new features to compensate the previous faults of CSS; and this trick is one of them.

Comment: Please don't make changes that only serve to bump the post or thread. Edits to posts, even your own, should be substantive.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, but I don't really understand your point. Why bumping?! Although it's not a good reason, but I've seen a lot of tiny bits of edits. For example, see the latest edit of the post below. Also, take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review). I don't understand what major (or even minor) impact it would have. Plus, even if we suppose you're correct, a down-vote to the whole answer is a bad reaction to such an action.

Comment: @MAChitgarha This doesn't have anything to do with edit *suggestions*; the issue here is that your changes don't make any difference/improvement to the content; the edits are being made just to "bump" the post. Also I'm not sure what you're talking about regarding downvotes.

Comment: @TylerH An edit should not only make improvements to the content, but it can improve, for example, readability and ordering, IMO. My intention was not bumping the post, but helping readers understanding my post a bit easier, even the change is pretty tiny. Even if you think I've not made any improvements, whether substantial or not, I don't think bumping a post (specially your own post) would be problematic, *simply because it does not have any negative impact on anything*.

Comment: @MAChitgarha When you make an edit to a post, you not only move to to the top of the answers list for anyone filtering on 'most recent answer activity', but you also cause the entire question to appear at the top of the questions page for anyone looking at the "activity" tab. If they see that they'll think "oh, a new answer or substantive change!" only to come here and see you changed a single word or added irrelevant styles. If you think your changes are improvements, OK, but maybe take more effort/time to make all the changes at once instead of one incremental change every few months.

Comment: @TylerH Oh, yes, that's a side-effect of such an edits. Thanks for your clarification. I would try to improve edits like this.

Answer (score 40):

Here is another option using Flexbox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.child {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, nemo.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

Here is a great article about centering in CSS. [Check it out](https://ishadeed.com/article/learn-css-centering/).

Answer (score 26):

**Flexible approach**

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #123456;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 24):

I saw the previous answers, and they will work only for that width of screen (not responsive). For the responsive you have to use flex.

Example:

```
div { display:flex; align-items:center; }
```

Answer (score 21):

The solution accepted as the answer is perfect to use `line-height` the same as the height of div, but this solution does not work perfectly when text is wrapped OR is in two lines.

Try this one if text is wrapped or is on multiple lines inside a div.

```css
#box
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For more reference, see:

- *[Vertically Center Multi-Lined Text](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)*
- *[6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)*

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following code snippet as the reference. It is working like a charm for me:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
}

.centered-text {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-text">
  <h1>Yes, it's my landing page</h1>
  <h2>Under construction, coming soon!!!</h2>
</div>
```

The output of the above code snippet is as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Try [this solution](http://codepen.io/hicTech/pen/emvMBw):

```css
.EXTENDER {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.PADDER-CENTER {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="EXTENDER">
  <div class="PADDER-CENTER">
    <div contentEditable="true">Edit this text...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Built using [CSS+](http://www.css.plus).

Comment: The [current syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) is just weird. Look at "-ms-flex-pack", "-webkit-justify-content", "-ms-flex-align", and "-webkit-align-items". And this is probably also incorrect: "-webkit-box-pack", "-moz-box-pack", "-webkit-box-align", and "-moz-box-align".

Answer (score 13):

You can also use below properties.

```
display: flex; 
align-content: center; 
justify-content : center;
```

Comment: Thanks 'satwik boorgula', I don't think your code problems, maybe there're some conflict in my code.

I test with this code:

<div id="topper" class="container">
    <span>Your Content!</span>
</div>

But it can fixed by use code as 'michielvoo' mentioned above.

Answer (score 12):

Another way:

Don't set the `height` attribute of the `div`, but instead use `padding:` to achieve the effect. Similarly to line-height, it only works if you have one line of text.  Although this way, if you have more content, the text will still be centered, but the div itself will be slightly larger.

So instead of going with:

```css
div {
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

You can say:

```css
div {
   padding: 60px 0; /* Maybe 60 minus font-size divided by two, if you want to be exact */
}
```

This will set the top and bottom `padding` of the `div` to `60px`, and the left and right `padding` to zero, making the `div` 120 pixels (plus the height of your font) high, and placing the text vertically centered in the div.

Answer (score 6):

The simple and versatile way is (as [Michielvoo's
table approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css/8865463#8865463)):

```css
[ctrv]{
    display: table !important;
}

[ctrv] > *{ /* Addressing direct descendants */
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      // text-align: center; /* Optional */
}
```

Using this attribute (or a equivalent class) on a parent tag works even for many children to align:

```html
<parent ctrv>  <ch1/>  <ch2/>   </parent>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure anyone has gone the `writing-mode` route, but I think it solves the problem cleanly and has **broad support**:

```css
.vertical {
  //border: 1px solid green;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.horizontal {
  //border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <div class="horizontal">
    <div class="content">
      I'm centered in the vertical and horizontal thing
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will, of course, work with any dimensions you need (besides 100% of the parent). If you uncomment the border lines, it'll be helpful to familiarize yourself.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Neithan/gudgd26v/) for you to fiddle.

[Caniuse support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode): 85.22% + 6.26% = **91.48%** (even Internet Explorer is in!)

Answer (score 5):

For a single line of text (or a single character) you can use this technique:

It **can** be used when `#box` has a non-fixed, **relative height in %**.

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

```css
#box::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 50%;
}

#box::after {
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "TextContent";
}
```

See a live demo [at JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ipujIyeM/2/edit?html,css,output) (easier to edit CSS) or [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47j7a/) (easier to change height of result frame).

If you want to place inner text in HTML, not in CSS, then you need to wrap text content in additional *inline* element and edit `#box::after` to match it. (And, of course, `content:` property should be removed.)

For example,
`<div id="box"><span>TextContent</span></div>`.
In this case, `#box::after` should be replaced with `#box span`.

For Internet Explorer 8 support you must replace `::` with `:`.

Comment: Out of all of the methods described here, yours was the only one that did the magic. My case: a div that had a span element with a spinning clock icon using css (for a loading layer). I just removed "TextContent" (leaving the property as an empty string) for #box::after and that was it.

Answer (score 5):

**For all your vertical alignment needs!**

Declare this Mixin:

```
@mixin vertical-align($position: relative) {
  position: $position;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Then include it in your element:

```
.element{
    @include vertical-align();
}
```

Comment: It works great. Just a comment for some readers: this code is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Even better idea for this. You can do like this too

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="centered">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A very simple & most powerful solution to vertically align center:

```css
.outer-div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <span class="inner">No data available</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is not vertical center....

Comment: It is if you change "top: 45%;" to "top:50%;". Just tried with one, two, three lines in a circle, and the center was aligned perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Try the transform property:

```css
 #box {
  height: 90px;
  width: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
 <div Id="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code will put the div in the middle of the screen regardless of screen size or `div` size:

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="center-screen">
 I'm in the center
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

See more details about `flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 3):

I would just like to extend [the answer from Michielvoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css/8865463#8865463) in order to release need for line-height and breathing of div height. It is basically just a simplified version like this:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  /* height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px; */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #123456;
  background-color: #bbbbff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>All grown-ups were once children... but only few of them remember it</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>And now here is my secret, a very simple secret: It is only with the heart that one can see rightly; what is essential is invisible to the eye.</span>
</div>
```

NOTE: commented out part of `css`is needed for `fixed-height` of enclosing `div`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
div {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the positioning method in CSS:

[Check the result here....](http://jsfiddle.net/mv376g1o/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="relativediv">
  <p>
    Make me vertical align as center
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.relativediv {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px
}
.relativediv p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transfrom: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error near "absolute".

Answer (score 2):

I needed a row of clickable elephants, vertically centered, but without using a table to get around some Internet Explorer 9 weirdness.

I eventually found the nicest CSS (for my needs) and it's great with Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer 11. Sadly Internet Explorer 9 is still laughing at me...

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.out {
  border: 3px solid silver;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="out" onclick="alert(1)">
  <div> <span><img src="http://www.birdfolk.co.uk/littleredsolo.png"/></span> </div>
  <div> <span>A lovely clickable option.</span> </div>
</div>

<div class="out" onclick="alert(2)">
  <div> <span><img src="http://www.birdfolk.co.uk/bang2/Ship01.png"/></span> </div>
  <div> <span>Something charming to click on.</span> </div>
</div>
```

*Obviously you don't need the borders, but they can help you see how it works.*

Answer (score 1):

Set it within `button` instead of `div` if you don't care about its little visual 3D effect.

```css
#box
{
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button Id="box" disabled>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want vertically center style means you can try `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`.

**Example:**

```css
#box
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 90px;
  width: 270px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div Id="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute Positioning and Stretching**

As with the method above this one begins by setting positioning on the parent and child elements as relative and absolute respectively. From there things differ.

In the code below I’ve once again used this method to center the child both horizontally and vertically, though you can use the method for vertical centering only.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {position: relative;}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The idea with this method is to try to get the child element to stretch to all four edges by setting the top, bottom, right, and left vales to 0. Because our child element is smaller than our parent elements it can’t reach all four edges.

Setting auto as the margin on all four sides however causes opposite margins to be equal and displays our child div in the center of the parent div.

Unfortunately the above won’t work in Internet Explorer 7 and below, and like the previous method the content inside the child div can grow too large, causing it to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
.element{position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

Add this small code in the CSS property of your element. It is awesome. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers now support the CSS `calc` function. If you are targeting these browsers you may want to look into doing something like this:

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: red">
  <span style="position: absolute; line-height: 40px; height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; top: calc(50% - 40px); left: calc(50% - 150px);">
    Here are two lines that will be centered even if the parent div changes size.
  </span>
</div>
```

The key is to use `style = "top: calc(50% - [innerFixedHeightInPX/2]px); height: [innerFixedHeightInPX]px;"` inside an absolute or relatively positioned parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .main{
        height:450px;
        background:#f8f8f8;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {  
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.height {
  line-height: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}

.transform { 
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
}

.transform p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h4>Using Height</h4>
<div class="box height">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit
</div>

<hr />

<h4>Using Transform</h4>
<div class="box transform">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Transform is [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565610/1218980) and [height as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865463/1218980) since a couple years already.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and very short:

```css
.block {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tile {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span class="tile">
    Hello middle world! :)
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

A better, easier, responsive approach is to set `margin-top` in CSS to around 45%:

```css
margin-top: 45%;
```

You might have to play with that number, but it will be in the center of the surrounding div.

Comment: This is not responsive at all. It's also not better, albeit maybe easier. This method will center the text only at a specific font size and height of the element. Change either one and you must fiddle with the magic number.

Comment: A very inaccurate method … Instead, you could use the CSS3 calc() function: `margin-top: calc(50% - [height of element]);`. But there are so many of solutions!

Answer (score -3):

[This](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/) works perfectly.

You have to use table style for the div and center align for the content.

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet in the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
.text{
   background: #ccc;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   width: 400px;
   line-height: 80px;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #000;
   float: left;
 }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This user is now deleted